# Definition of exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

Take a sequence $A \to B \to C \to 0$ of modules over a commutative ring. 
How would one show that it is exact? I understand the necessary surjectivity of $B \to C$, but what about the first map?

Answer (score 3):

Remember that "exact" means "At each point, the kernel of the next map equals the image of the previous map." So saying $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0$ is exact is saying:

- $im(B\rightarrow C)=ker(C\rightarrow 0)$, and
- $im(A\rightarrow B)=ker(B\rightarrow C)$.

Now the former is equivalent to saying "$im(B\rightarrow C)=C$", since the kernel of any map from $C$ to $0$ is all of $C$.

The latter, meanwhile, isn't simplifiable: you just have to check that indeed $im(A\rightarrow B)=ker(B\rightarrow C)$.

---

Note that exactness is a property, not of the sequence of modules, but of the sequence of *maps between* modules. For instance, suppose $A=B=C=\mathbb{Z}$ (as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules). Then if we let $id$ be the identity map and $z: x\mapsto 0$, we have:

- $A\xrightarrow{id}B\xrightarrow{id}C\rightarrow 0$ is **not** exact, but
- $A\xrightarrow{z}B\xrightarrow{id}C\rightarrow 0$ **is** exact.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to show that $\textrm{im} (A \to B) = \textrm{ker} (B \to C)$. It would be easier if you just remembered that condition because then the surjectivity follows from that, namely

$$\textrm{im} (B \to C) = \textrm{ker} (C \to 0) = C$$

Comment: Is there a way to do this if I don't know information about A->B and B->C? If there was a zero on the left side it would be sufficient to show that A->B is injective.

Comment: Sorry I just edited my question as you responded.

Comment: You have no information at all about those two maps?

Comment: In any case, you're probably better off asking a new question. This time, include the actual problem you wish to solve with all the information given.